# AWS EC2 instance connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect AWS EC2 instance through webservice by providing Ec2 instance username and key pair name and private key.
Is this possible from java webservice ?

Comment: Can you expand on / clarify your question? AWS KeyPairs are used with SSH to connect AWS EC2 instances. A Java Web Service could use the SSH KeyPair along with the SSH protocol to connect to and transfer files to/from EC2 instances.

Comment: I mean, suppose if we have accesskey/secret key then using below code we can connect to AWS     amazonIdentityManagementClient = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(awsCredentials);   so simlarly if I have ec2 instance username , key pair alias name, privatekey. Do we have any api to connect to ec2 instance and do operations on it ?

Comment: An Amazon EC2 instance is just like any other computer running the chosen operating system (Linux, Windows). The fact that it is an EC2 instance has no impact on how you would do this activity.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting to EC2 from your Web Browser (It required Java enabled) . [Here is a link to Amazon's page which has a section on it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/step-2-connect-to-instance.html)

Comment: The OP wants to connect programmatically, not through web UI...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it mentions "from Web Service", Programmatic access isnt referenced.